# Calculating Listbox Items

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm stuck on following:

I have an application gui as follows:

[image]

I created a seperate class library for 'klant' which contains a string 'Naam' and an integer 'Consumpties'and linked this to my project.

When the user adds a name (Naam) and a number of consumptions (Consumpties), these values are addes to a listbox.

Here is my code so far:

```
private void btnKlantToevoegen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Klant> klanten = new List<Klant>();

        klanten.Add(new Klant
        {
           Naam = txtKlantNaam.Text,
           Consumpties = int.Parse(txtKlantConsumpties.Text)
        }
           );

            for (int i = 0; i < klanten.Count; i++)
            {

                lbOverzicht.Items.Add(klanten[i]);

            }
```

I need to calculate the sum of the entered clients and consumptions, but i'm stuck on how to properly achieve this.

Also, there needs to be set a maximum number of consumptions per client and a maximum of total consumptions.

How to call this?

I tried creating a method to calculate the total of consumptions, but am not able to accomplish results. The code i have for this so far is as follows:

```
int BerekenTotaalConsumpties(int totaalconsumpties)
    {
        totaalconsumpties = 0;
        int consumpties = int.Parse(txtKlantConsumpties.Text);
        for (int i = 0; i <= consumpties; i++)
        {
            totaalconsumpties += Convert.ToInt32(lbOverzicht.Items[i].ToString());
        }
        return totaalconsumpties;
    }
```

The result of this method then needs to be places in a label. I would do this as follows:

```
lblOverzicht.Content = BerekenTotaalConsumpties();
```

Klant class as follows:

```
 public class Klant
{
    public string Naam;
    public int Consumpties;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} ({1})", this.Naam, this.Consumpties);
    }
}
```

How can the names (Naam) be sorted alphabetically?
Untill now we have

```
lbOverzicht.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

But this doens't seem to work?

How can we verify that the users enters letters in field Naam and numbers in field Consumptions?

Comment: Can you post your Klant class? Have you tried parsing through `klanten` and adding up each value of `Klant.Consumpties`? You can also use that parse to count the entries so as to get the count of names.

Comment: Please add it to the OP, not in the comment, so it's easier to read.

Comment: Updated the question with the Klant class

Comment: @WilliamV you don't need to make a new list to only add 1 customer (klant), and you don't do calculations of values directly from on listbox. Do the calculations on the customer objects them self.

Answer (score 1):

For the counting, try this:

```
int totalNaams = 0;
int totalConsumpties = 0;
foreach (Klant item in klanten)
{
    totalConsumpties += item.Consumpties;
    totalNaams += 0;
}
```

As for limiting the number of Consumpties per client, that needs to be done before you add it to the listbox. Just check to see if it's less than or equal to your max.

For limiting the total Comsumpties, You will need to calculate the new total after each new addition to the ListView. That would probably require a different approach to the counting so you're not executing the foreach more times that you need to.

#### New XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="lbOverzicht" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Margin="435,372,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="177">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Naam}" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Consumpties}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

#### New Code-Behind

```
int totalNaams = 0;
int totalConsumpties = 0;
int consumptiesTotalMax = 0;
int consumptiesMax = 0;
List<Klant> klanten = new List<Klant>();

public class Klant
{
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    public int Consumpties { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} ({1})", this.Naam, this.Consumpties);
    }
}

public void btnKlantToevoegen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int current = int.Parse(txtKlantConsumpties.Text);
    consumptiesTotalMax = int.Parse(txtTotalMax.Text);
    consumptiesMax = int.Parse(txtConsumpMax.Text);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtKlantConsumpties.Text.Trim()) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtKlantNaam.Text.Trim()))
    {
        if (((totalConsumpties + current) <= consumptiesTotalMax) && (current <= consumptiesMax))
        {
            klanten.Add(new Klant
                {
                    Naam = txtKlantNaam.Text,
                    Consumpties = current
                }
            );

            lbOverzicht.ItemsSource = klanten;

            totalConsumpties += current;
            totalNaams += 1;

            CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lbOverzicht.ItemsSource);
            view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Naam", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the requirement of different approach about limiting the consumptions?

Comment: Updated now. Tweaked a couple things.

Comment: You declare Naam as integer, while it is a string no? To know the number of names, we just need to count the total of items?

Comment: I never actually use the string value of `Naam`, I just count every time a new item is added to the ListBox. That's the `int` your see. It's just a counting `int`.

Comment: Okay. An other upcoming question would be how to alphabetically sort the names. I know there is a function .Sort() but I can't see to get it in the right place.

Comment: Try that update with `lbOverzicht.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(
    New SortDescription("", ListSortDirection.Ascending));`

Comment: Why can't I Parse the integer int consumptiesTotalMax ? When I try to Parse like int consumptiesTotalMax = int.Parse(txtconsumptiestotalmax.text) i get an error ...

Comment: Also, how to best implement condition: if naam contains number, then MessageBox.Show that it needs to contain letter, if consumpties contains letter or negative number, MessageBox.Show ... ?

Comment: @WilliamV I can't accurately assess the error you're getting without more information. Update the post with the error and where it's occurring. The code in my answer has been tested and works on my side. Also, please update the OP with all your new questions so that an outsider can follow all the new additions. I would recommend looking into Regex and assigning some to the `TextChanged` event of the textboxes to handle invalid characters.

Comment: You're getting the error because you can't reference a textbox from outside of a method. You have to declare the variable and then set it to the textbox inside of the Main method of your program or inside of the `btnKlantToevoegen_Click` method. Check update.

Comment: When adding second item, i get a InvalidOperationException from the sorting saying it failes to compare two elements.

Comment: Also, when setting max consumptions to 20 and adding per 5, i'm able to add 25 (5 times 5 consumptions) ... any clue?

Comment: I'm still working on the sort fix. As for the max consumptions, it's limiting my total to 20 on my implementation.

Comment: And TotaalNamen += 0; stays 0 i believe ?

Comment: Try and limit to 22. Thx.

Comment: It was looking at the current total not the future total with what's currently in process of being added.

Comment: The Names are not being counted, += 0 ?

Comment: Yes, sorry that should be += 1

Comment: Did you find a solution regarding the sorting?

Comment: Not at the moment. I don't have all the testing tools on my home computer at the moment so I can only give tested advice on Monday. Have you tried googling "Sort a Listview" and trying to results?

Comment: Got the sorting to work. Check update. Changed from ListBox to ListView. Hope thats fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use the power of `MVVM` and the `CollectionChange` event of an `ObservableCollection` to handle the summing of any and all changes to that collection.

---

In your view model (which adheres to `INotifyPropertyChange`) declare these properties

```
// Zehn Kleine Jagermeister!
public ObservableCollection<Klant> Overzicht
{
    get { return _Overzicht; }
    set { _Overzicht = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}

public int AantalKlanten { get { return Overzicht?.Count ?? 0; } }
public int AantalConsumpties { get; set; }
```

So we have the list of `Klant`s and the totals. Then in the constructor of the viewmodel we allocate the observable collection and subscribe to the change of collection event:

```
Overzicht = new ObservableCollection<Klant>();

Overzicht.CollectionChanged += (o, args) =>
{
    AantalConsumpties = Overzicht.Sum(klnt => klnt.Consumpties);
    OnPropertyChanged("AantalConsumpties");
    OnPropertyChanged("AantalKlanten");
};
```

So whenever we add or remove something from the collection, we recalculate the totals. By directly calling the `OnPropertyChanged` methods for the totals we announce to the XAML controls which have bound to those properties, that the values have changed and to update them for the user to see.

Here is the binding in XAML

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Overzicht}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding AantalKlanten }"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding AantalConsumpties}"/>
```

Then to limit things on add of the button click, simply check `AantalKlanten` and `AantalCompties` before allowing an insertion (`Add`) into the Overzicht collection.

The below shows the add in a button click with a max of 100. You can change it as needed.

```
if ((myViewModel.AantalConsumpties + newvalue) < 100)
    myViewModel.Overzicht.Add(new Klant() { Naam = ..., Consumpties = newvalue});
```

---

This is the `Klant`

```
public class Klant
{
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    public int Consumpties { get; set; }

}
```

---

New to MVVM? Check out my quick example here [Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int NumConsumptionsPerClient(string client) 
{
    var aux = listBox1.Items;
    List<int> consumptions = new List<int>();
    foreach (var i in aux)
    {
        if (i.ToString().Contains(client))
        {
            consumptions.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(i.ToString(), @"\d+").Value)); // only gets numbers
        }
    }
    int sumconsumptions = 0;
    foreach (int k in consumptions)
    {
        sumconsumptions = sumconsumptions + k;
    }
    return sumconsumptions;
}

public int NumConsumptions()
{
    var aux = listBox1.Items;
    List<int> consumptions = new List<int>();
    foreach (var i in aux)
    {
        consumptions.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(i.ToString(), @"\d+").Value)); // only gets numbers
    }
    int sumconsumptions = 0;
    foreach (int k in consumptions)
    {
        sumconsumptions = sumconsumptions + k;
    }
    return sumconsumptions;
}

 public int NumClients()
        {
            return listBox1.Items.Count;            
        }
```

With first method you can control the max. consumptions per client. (you modify the method for your object instead of string)

Second and third methods are easy to understand.

Comment: Can this be placed in a method and the be called as label.Content=method ?

Comment: Ofc, just return both int (`sumconsumptions` and `sumclients`)

Comment: Updated for your 2nd question